# Using BeautifulSoup in Python, how to separate data until next <h3> tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

Question is a little bit confusing but i hope example below will clarify things.

I try to scrape data from one (and only) `<div>` tag in a page.

Problem 1: All data in that div is all put together and separated only by `<h3>` tags.

Problem 2: There is variable number of `<p>` tags after `<h3>` tag and `h3` tag can be either Title1 or Title2.

How can i parse that div element and split all data into some kind of array/dict structure that holds only `h3` tags and all `p` tags until next `h3` tag

[image: Problem explanation]?

Picture says it all.

My code so far (that works and scrapes the data):

```
links = soup.find('div', class_='DIV I WANT')

for p in links.find_all(['p', 'h3']):
print p.text.strip()
```

EDIT:

Full html added. Yes, it's written exactly like that. Data obviously slightly changed:

```
<div class="table">


    <p>
            List of actors.
    </p>


    <p>
            date 25.09.2017
    </p>



    <h3>
            Actor
    </h3>
    <p>
        Office
        <br>
        Address 1 8, 100 City 15
        <br>
        Address 2 250, 200 City 15
    </p>

        <p>
                08h00-12h30  13h15-16h45&lt;br&gt;08h00-12h30  13h00-15h00  
        </p>


        <p>
            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" title="Actors" class="fonticon">www.example.com<span data-icon="l"></span></a>
        </p>


        <p>

                info@example.com
                <br>

        </p>


        <p>

                012/123 45 67
                <br>

        </p>


        <p>
                telefax 123/123 45 67
        </p>


    <h3>
            Actress
    </h3>
    <p>
        Personal address
        <br>
        Address 7, 20 City 2
        <br>
        Address 5, 30 City 2
    </p>

        <p>
                8h15-12h30 13h30-16h30(lu-ma-je)16h45 me&lt;br&gt;8h15-12h30
        </p>


        <p>
            <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" title="Actress" class="fonticon">www.example.com<span data-icon="l"></span></a>
        </p>


        <p>

                info@example.com
                <br>

        </p>


        <p>

                023/999 99 99
                <br>

                023/999 99 88 phone1
                <br>

                023/999 99 77 phone2
                <br>

        </p>


        <p>
                telefax 001/333 44 55&lt;br&gt;telefax 001/000 00 10 ppts
        </p>


    <h3>
            Actor
    </h3>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add the html code to  your question. That makes it easier for us to better understand and solve the issue you are having.

Comment: Added html, hopefully it will help.

Comment: Can you possibly add in the question your goal output? So that we can understand more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Goal output would be .csv file with h3 tag as a first item in a row, p tags as other items and new line starts with another h3 tag. Because of variable items in p tags i understand this would be practically impossible to correctly do but i wouldn't mind doing some manual work in a excel after that tweaking cells left/right.

Answer (score 1):

Use [select](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class/) to select all h3 tags and [.next_siblings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) to iterate and add the text of each element until you find the next h3 tag

```
data = []
titles = soup.select('.table h3') 
for title in titles:
  if('Title1' or 'Title2' in title:
    item = {"title":title.get_text(),"description":""}

    for sibling in title.next_siblings:
      #stop when you reach the next tag
      if(sibling.name == "h3"):
        break;

      try:
        item['description']  += sibling.get_text()
      except:
        pass
    data.append(item)
print(data)
```

Comment: As i understand, this doesn't take into account my h3 tag can be either Title1 or Title2, am i wrong?

Comment: You're correct. Add an if statement 
      `if("Title1" or "Title2" in  title.get_text()):`

Comment: Can you clarify that "description":"" part?

Comment: `item = {"title":title.get_text(),"description":""}` creates a dictionary with keys `title` and `description`. `description` is set to an empty string and `title` is set to the text of the `h3` element